# wp_add_inline_style not add to queue

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add css to .css file with function wp_add_inline_style() but when it run , it's adding css to  of page under `<style>` tag without add to .css file I enqueue (file is empty) . Please give me some advise . Thanks a lot

```
wp_enqueue_style('custom-css', fw_get_framework_directory_uri( '/static/css/custom.css' ));
wp_add_inline_style('custom-css', $custom_css);
```

Comment: It does not add CSS to your CSS file. Those CSS will be load while running just after the CSS file. You can check it from viewing the source code of the page.

Comment: And this function add to source code page under style tag right ?

Answer (score 2):

`wp_add_inline_style()` does not add CSS to your stylesheet. Those custom CSS you add with `wp_add_inline_style()` will be loadedjust after the CSS file. You can confirm this by viewing source code of the page.

Lets say you are trying to add some style in Twenty Nineteen theme. Example:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentynineteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.0' );
wp_add_inline_style( 'twentynineteen-style', 'p{font-size:16px;}' );
```

Using `wp_add_inline_style()` you can add you custom style.

Now in the source code, you can see like this.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentynineteen-style-css'  href='http://review.test/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/style.css?ver=1561096667' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='twentynineteen-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
p{font-size:16px;}
</style>
```

You can see that the custom CSS is displayed inside `<style>` tag just after main stylesheet is loading.